# rsync copy over only certain types of files using include option

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I use the following bash script to copy only files of certain extension(in this case *.sh), however it still copies over all the files.  what's wrong?

```
from=$1
to=$2

rsync -zarv  --include="*.sh" $from $to
```

Comment: While not strictly speaking related, I would suggest quoting $from/$to. Not doing so may give you unexpected results if positional arguments 1/2 include spaces.

Comment: did you get an understanding why your command wouldn't just work?

Comment: @CharlieParker: Do you have to use `rsync`, this can very well be achieved with the shell internals?

Comment: What this question and its answers also lack is how to craft the command if I have recursive directories that I want to send only one type of file. It seems it only does it for the target directory...

Comment: side note: the `-r` is redundant because `-a` implies `-r`

Answer (score 338, accepted):

I think `--include` is used to include a subset of files that are otherwise excluded by `--exclude`, rather than including only those files.
In other words: you have to think about *include* meaning **don't exclude**.

Try instead:

```
rsync -zarv  --include "*/" --exclude="*" --include="*.sh" "$from" "$to"
```

For rsync version 3.0.6 or higher, the order needs to be modified as follows (see comments):

```
rsync -zarv --include="*/" --include="*.sh" --exclude="*" "$from" "$to"
```

Adding the `-m` flag will avoid creating empty directory structures in the destination. Tested in  version 3.1.2.

So if we only want *.sh files we have to exclude all files `--exclude="*"`, include all directories `--include="*/"` and include all *.sh files `--include="*.sh"`.

You can find some good examples in the section **Include/Exclude Pattern Rules** of the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: While it'll get you all sub-directories, if there's any .sh files in subdirectories you want to rsync, chances are you'll want to use --include="*/" too.

Comment: I tried this on rsync version 3.0.7, which I got long ago from macports, and it didn't work with this ordering of includes/excludes. This is what I ended up with that worked for me (adapted for OP): `rsync -zarv --include="*/" --include="*.sh" --exclude="*" "$from" "$to"`.

Comment: I tried with rsync 3.0.9 and it did not work. Bijou is right, the ordering is not proper (first `--include=\*.sh` then `--exclude=\*`)

Comment: It doesn't work with your ordering of includes/exludes, but it works with the ordering suggested by Bijou Trouvaille

Comment: It doesn't handle `--delete` very well. For example after deleting **a.sh** on source, if I pass `--delete` , it tries to remove everything from destination. How to solve this?

Comment: @BijouTrouvaille's ordering worked for me even with version 3.0.6 and the other ordering does not.

Comment: why do we need so many includes, looks like a really silly command.

Comment: I think an explanation of what the command is actually doing would be fantastic and really useful.

Comment: does it matter where you run the command? I usually use absolute paths everywhere...

Comment: How does one craft the command if I have recursive directories that I want to send only one type of file. It seems it only does it for the target directory.

Comment: I want to include only one directory and exclude rest of all directory in `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua` file. Have any idea?

Comment: exclude '*' is super important:D

Comment: `rsync` is a really great tool...  *except* for this this functionality here. These `--include` and `--exclude` flags are unintuitive and sloppy.

Comment: why is it accepted as a correct answer? It also copies all subdirectories even if they don't contain the goal files

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov that can be fixed with `--prune-empty-dirs`. Why that's not a default action I'm not entirely sure, but it isn't so we (almost always) need to include it.

Comment: This does'nt work if I want to copy just some certain folder i.e. if the pattern represent some folder

Comment: I am on macos and rsync version 2.6.9, but it still behaves like "rsync version 3.0.6 or higher"

Comment: Weirdly, `--dry-run` doesn't seem to show any transfers when I use include/exclude, even though the transfers actually work and are filtered correctly in live mode.

Answer (score 97):

The answer by @chepner will copy all the sub-directories whether it contains files or not. If you need to exclude the sub-directories that don't contain the file and still retain the directory structure, use

```
rsync -zarv  --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/"  --include="*.sh" --exclude="*" "$from" "$to"
```

Comment: This was a requirement for me: "If you need to exclude the sub-directories that dont contain the file and still retain the directory structure" +1

Comment: I don't understand how did you know what the order of the --includes were?

Comment: How does one craft the command if I have recursive directories that I want to send only one type of file. It seems it only does it for the target directory.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Also curious about the `--include "*/"` - The FILTER RULES of the rsync man say, "the first matching pattern is acted on" so I can't figure out why this doesn't work if we just use the second include (`--include="*.sh"`) - won't this be the first matching pattern that acts on the file we want?

Comment: Was rsync designed to be unusable if it falls into enemy hands?!

Answer (score 47):

Here's the important part from the man page:

> As the list of files/directories to transfer is built, rsync checks each name to be transferred against the list of include/exclude patterns in turn, and the first matching pattern is acted on: if it is an exclude pattern, then that file is skipped; if it is an include pattern then that  filename  is not skipped; if no matching pattern is found, then the filename is not skipped.

To summarize:

- Not matching any pattern means a file will be copied!
- The algorithm quits once any pattern matches

Also, something ending with a slash is matching directories (like `find -type d` would).

Let's pull apart this answer from above.

```
rsync -zarv  --prune-empty-dirs --include "*/"  --include="*.sh" --exclude="*" "$from" "$to"
```

1. Don't skip any directories
2. Don't skip any `.sh` files
3. Skip everything
4. (Implicitly, don't skip anything, but the rule above prevents the default rule from ever happening.)

Finally, the `--prune-empty-directories` keeps the first rule from making empty directories all over the place.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining what's going on. Now there's much better chance that I won't forget the command.

Comment: _''The algorithm quits once any pattern matches"_ — this is key, and none of the higher-rated answers explain it as clearly and as up-front as you did here. Of course this _is_ in the man page somehwere, and if I'd read the whole thing carefully, I'd've seen that. Still, thanks.

Comment: The other key concept is that "when using the --recursive (-r) option (which is implied by -a), every subdir component of every path is visited left to right, with each directory having a chance for exclusion before its content. In this way include/exclude patterns are applied recursively to the pathname of each node".

Comment: *''The algorithm quits once any pattern matches"*  -- If this is true then shouldn't `--include "*/"` allow any file to be sync'd that is in any directory? Or does matching a file require matching on a directory pattern AND matching on a file pattern?

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy - "`a '*' matches any path component, but it stops at slashes.`"

Comment: @Jim Hunziker - That doesn't make any sense to me at all? I need baby English. I don't understand what `*/`does. I think it matches all directories and does not match any files, this was the second part of my last comment. It that is true then I think I understand your command.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy I think it means that the star eats up parts of the path but if your pattern has a slash after the star, the slash and things after it still need to be in the path. So the first star in `*/foo/*` won't eat up the `foo` directory you're trying to ensure is in there.

Answer (score 20):

One more addition: if you need to sync files by its extensions in **one dir only** (without of recursion) you should use a construction like this:

```
rsync -auzv --include './' --include '*.ext' --exclude '*' /source/dir/ /destination/dir/
```

Pay your attention to the dot in the first `--include`. `--no-r` does not work in this construction.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to gbyte.co for the valuable comment!

**EDIT:**

The `-uzv` flags are not related to this question directly, but I included them because I use them usually.

Comment: how did you know what the order of the flags had to be and what they needed to include?

Comment: @CharlieParker, because the rsync uses the `include` and the `exclude` options in the order which they were specified in. In addition to this, it stops at the first matched one. So, if we specify the `--exclude '*'` at the first place in this example the rsync will do nothing. See the man for more explanations.

Comment: can you explain to me what each flag is doing? First flag `-- include './' ` is saying include everything in the source directory path? Then the next one ` --include '.ext'` include the specific file in the source path named `.ext` and then the exclude says don't send anything else `--exclude '*'`? Is that correct?

Comment: How does one craft the command if I have recursive directories that I want to send only one type of file. It seems it only does it for the target directory.

Comment: @CharlieParker, the first `include` says to process current directory, the second one -- a files with specified extension and, finally, the `exclude` says to skip all other files and directories.

Comment: Thanks for this! Needs to `--include '*.ext'` and not `--include '.ext'`

Comment: if the flags `-u`, `-z` or `-v` are not significant to the answer, consider removing them

Answer (score 3):

Wrote this handy function and put in my bash scripts or `~/.bash_aliases`. Tested sync'ing locally on Linux with bash and `awk` installed. It works

```
selrsync(){
# selective rsync to sync only certain filetypes;
# based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111793/588867
# Example: selrsync 'tsv,csv' ./source ./target --dry-run
types="$1"; shift; #accepts comma separated list of types. Must be the first argument.
includes=$(echo $types| awk  -F',' \
    'BEGIN{OFS=" ";}
    {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { if (length($i) > 0) $i="--include=*."$i; } print
    }')
restargs="$@"

echo Command: rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include="*/" $includes --exclude="*" "$restargs"
eval rsync -avz --prune-empty-dirs --include="*/" "$includes" --exclude="*" $restargs
}
```

### Advantages:

short handy and extensible when one wants to add more arguments (i.e. `--dry-run`).

### Example:

```
selrsync 'tsv,csv' ./source ./target --dry-run
```

Answer (score -1):

If someone looks for this…
I wanted to rsync only specific files and folders and managed to do it with this command: `rsync --include-from=rsync-files`

With rsync-files:

```
my-dir/
my-file.txt

- /*
```