# Rsync including all files

Tags: bash, rsync

After some reading and trying [rsync copy over only certain types of files using include option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111562/rsync-copy-over-only-certain-types-of-files-using-include-option) I can't get seem to get it to work.

I run the following command:

```
rsync -zarv -vvv -e ssh --prune-empty-dirs --delete --include="*/" --include="*.csv" 
--include="*.hdf5" --include="*.pickle" --include="*.tar.gz" --include="*.bin" 
--include="*.zip" --include="*.npz" --exclude="*" . user@host.com:/rsync
```

But at the target it backups any file I have in the directory and subdirectories. delete-before and delete-after does not delete files like .txt or .py. I have also tried the --exclude="*" before the extension includes but I am running 2.6.9 so it should be after as far as I have understood it.

Deleting files on the host machine will just sync them again for whatever reason I don't know.

Comment: I am running on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Amani: `--exclude="*"` will exclude everything except for what is included with `--include`.

Comment: Yes I have already deleted my comment :)

Comment: try `rsync -zarv -vvv -e ssh --prune-empty-dirs  --include="*/" --include="*.csv" 
--include="*.hdf5" --include="*.pickle" --include="*.tar.gz" --include="*.bin" 
--include="*.zip" --include="*.npz" --exclude="*" . user@host.com:/rsync --delete`  .. just add delete at the end of your command

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks fine, although try using **`--delete-excluded`** instead of `--delete`.

> `--delete-excluded` - also delete excluded files from destination dirs

It should eliminate any files that are `--excluded` and not `--included` on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have bothered. This was a bash issue and not a command issue.

As I was using the command:

```
exec $COMMAND
```

instead of

```
eval $COMMAND
```

This made god knows what for error but executing it manually (after print) and correctly in bash made it work. Deleting items still seems flaky but that I can try some.