# Regex to exclude all files except .csv files with gsutil rsync

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, rsync

I am trying to create an rsync command to upload files into a bucket on Google Cloud Storage.

We want to go through the entire computer and upload only `csv` files into the bucket. I know that the `rsync` command for `gsutil` provides a command to exclude files (`-x`), but I am having trouble figuring out the regex to exclude all files except .csv files.

For example, if I have these files in these directories:

`folder/folder/hello.csv`

`folder/folder/results.pdf`

`folder/folder2/test.txt`

`folder/folder3/hello2.csv`

I expect to only upload:

`folder/folder/hello.csv`

`folder/folder3/hello2.csv`

Any idea on how this regex would look?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rsync copy over only certain types of files using include option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111562/rsync-copy-over-only-certain-types-of-files-using-include-option)

Comment: @Cyrus I'm not sure if gsutil rsync command is the same as the native rsync command, I was looking at this documentation https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync and it seems that there isn't an include or exclude option.

Comment: `find . -name '*.csv' | xargs -I {} gsutil cp {} gs://<bucket-name>`

Answer (score 4):

The [gsutil rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) command takes an option `-x` to exclude patterns given in Python [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) syntax. The latter link has an example of using negative lookahead to match "all but" the filename extension `.bat`. So you could try

```sh
-n -x '.*[.](?!csv$)[^.]*$'
```

The `-n` is to show what would happen.