# rsync: How to apply a recursively include filter while excluding other files

Tags: shell, sh, rsync

I'm trying to `rsync` a folder, but only some specific contents matching pattern and exluding the remaining files.
I tried many solutions, followed advices from [#2503](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2503) and [#11111793](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111793), but I can't achieve a *simple* (at least in my mind) copy :/

This is my folders tree :

```
/
  - A
  - B.html
  css/
    - .gitkeep
    - source.css
    - source.min.css
    - source.min.css.map
    sub/
      - source.css
      - source.min.css
      - source.min.css.map
      - ...
  js/
    - ... Same as CSS
  img/
    - image.png
    - sub/
      - image.png
      - ...
```

The goal is to rsync :

- `/*.html` All HTML files at root (no other file types)
- `/css/**/*.min.css` All built files into /css and subfolders recursively
- `/css/**/*.min.css.map` All mapping files into /css and subfolders recursively
- `/js/**/*.min.js` All built files into /js and subfolders recursively
- `/js/**/*.min.js.map` All mapping files into /js and subfolders recursively
- `/img/**/*` All files into /img and subfolders recursively

I tried so many things, like include `/*` and exclude `*`, etc.

An example :

```
rsync -zarv \
  --include="/*.html" \
  --include="/js/**/*/min.js" \
  --include="/js/**/*.min.js.map" \
  --include="/css/**/*.min.css" \
  --include="/css/**/*.min.css.map" \
  --include="/img/***" \
  --exclude="*" \
  --delete \
  ./ $to
```

The 3 stars helped me for the `img/` folder and copy it with everything inside, including subfolders ; it didn't work with `/img/*` nor with `/img/**/*` (no files synced, not even the `img` folder itself).

I don't understand... what I don't understand -.-'

Could someone help me ?

Subsidiary question : the glob pattern `/js/**/*.min.*` doesn't seem to work, can we use wildcard only at start of paths ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first including folders themselves:

```
rsync -zarv \
  --include="/*.html" \
  --include="/js/" \
  --include="/js/**/" \
  --include="/js/**.min.js" \
  --include="/js/**.min.js" \
  --include="/js/**.min.js.map" \
  --include="/css/" \
  --include="/css/**/" \
  --include="/css/**.min.css" \
  --include="/css/**.min.css.map" \
  --include="/img/***" \
  --exclude="*" \
  --delete \
  ./ "$to"/
```

Comment: It works :) So, it's a very long rule juste for a simple view... Can simplify a little the "*.min.*", but it stays a little bit huge xD Thanks !